# Advantage Database Local server with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, connection-string, advantage-database-server

Hi I am trying to connect through JDBC on an Advantage local server.

I have tested many connections strings, like for example:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                     "jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262;catalog=C:\\bdl\\database\\BDL.add;TableType=cdx;LockType=proprietary", "adssys", "no");
```

I am searching for over three days now. I am getting always the error message connection refused. I only want to connect and access the files , and not on any advanced database server. I have now idea any more.

Answer (score 3):

The ADS JDBC driver doesn't support ALS (Advantage Local Server), you have to install an actual ADS server.

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/devguide_ads_and_java_1.htm

If you have a running ADS server make sure there is no firewall that blocks traffic on port 6262 (or whatever port you're using).